# How to initialise classes correctly

Tags: ios, swift, class, sprite-kit, initialization

The following code produces an error on the line `pickUp.spawnShield()` from my GameScene class whenever I try to call it.

There is no message from the compiler about what is causing the error, though I think it may be to do with the fact that my `var pickUp: Pickup!` is nil. If thats the case, how do I initialise it correctly?

```
class Pickup {

    var game: GameScene!

    func spawnShield() {

        let randomXStart = Random().random(min: game.gameArea.minX + game.player.size.width/2, max: game.gameArea.maxX - game.player.size.width/2)

        let randomXEnd = Random().random(min: game.gameArea.minX + game.player.size.width/2, max: game.gameArea.maxX - game.player.size.width/2)

        let startPoint = CGPoint(x: randomXStart, y: game.size.height * 1.1)
        let endPoint = CGPoint(x: randomXEnd, y: -game.size.height * 0.1)

        let shield = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shieldDrop")
        shield.setScale(2)
        shield.position = startPoint
        shield.zPosition = 3

        game.addChild(shield)

        let moveShield = SKAction.move(to: endPoint, duration: TimeInterval(Helper().randomBetweenTwoNumbers(firstNumber: 3, secondNumber: 5)))

        shield.run(moveShield)
    }
}
```

Then I call it in my class like so:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var pickUp: Pickup!

    override init(size: CGSize) {

        ....

        pickUp = Pickup() //something like this?

        super.init(size: size)
    }

    func startNewLevel() {

        pickUp.spawnShield()
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `startNewLevel()`?

Comment: = Pickup() <- is this what you're after?

Comment: Do you assign pickUp to anything anywhere, and can you be sure that happens before the call to startNewLevel?

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed It's called in `touchesBegan`
@benjiiiii If I do that, then I get a nil in my PickUp class saying theres a nil value on the first line.
@Sune Haven't assigned pickUp to anything.

Comment: How do you declare gamescene?  My guess is you are using the default template, which uses `GameScene(fileNamed:)`  This does not use the `init(size:)` method, it uses the `required init(coder aDecoder:NSCoder)` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: you have to create an instance of Pickup class stored (referenced) in var pickUp. I do not see anything like

```
class Pickup {
  weak var game: GameScene?
  init(game: GameScene) {
    self.game = game
  }
  func spawnShield() {...}
}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
  var pickUp: Pickup!
  override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)
    pickUp = Pickup(game: self)
}
```

Second: I do not see too much reason to have pickUp implicitly unwrapped (!). I would rather propose *weak var pickUp: Pickup?* to avoid reference cycle (if referenced in cycle)

Third: it is strange that you see no compiler error of missing initializer, as you have properties in your classes and then initializer must be defined. Do not forget to call *super.init(...)* in your initializer, after you initialize your class properties.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by the `game` argument. I've edited my code show what's going on in my PickUp class. I think the problem may be to do with the `var game: GameScene!` as it's failing on the first line of `spawnShield()`

Comment: I do not know how your initializer is declared. I would expect that will take at least one argument that will be stored in the game property (dependency injection). Do you really have no initializer declared in the Pickup class???

Comment: No. The code there is what there is. In the Pickup class there are 2 functions that are called in the GameScene.

Comment: When I copy your Pickup class into my Swift Playground, I see error **Class 'Pickup' has no initializers**

Comment: implicitly unwrapping does not cause reference cycles, it just doesnt do the if nil do nothing check

Comment: @MichaelBernat Oh right I see. Ok it works great now. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Hi just curious... am just reading he swift book. His Pickup class has just one property defined which is an optional so it should be set to nil. Doesn’t that mean that Pickup has a default initializer?

Comment: @Azzaknight yes it has the default init, there is no reason to create a new one, and if anything this new init that was created should be a convenience init

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Would it be correct to say that by adding the new init(game:)  the default init is no longer provided automatically- hence it’s not defined as a convenience initializer as now the new custom init is the only designated initializer.

Comment: @Azzaknight no, it still exists

Comment: @Knight0fDragon For classes (structs have another rules), you have always have default initializer *init()* till you provide default values for all your class properties (optionals are nil by default). But dependency injection is standard and efficient pattern - putting *self* as an argument in the initializer. Just avoid retain cycles (hence weak var).

Answer (score 0):

here, I think you can do somthing like this

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var pickUp = Pikup()

    func startNewLevel() {

        pickUp.spawnShield()
    }
}
```

or you can just initialize you variable "pikUp" before calling spawnShield(), maybe in init method as you wrote.

so also make sure that you use 'game' variable after initializing it, because as I can see in your code it will also crash because it is nil when you use it.

Comment: Thanks. How do I initialise the game variable?

Comment: you initialize game property in the Pickup class initializer. I do not see any, and there must be at least one - you have new class and you have at least one property there.

Comment: @MichaelBernat Why do they not show in the drop down menu then if I have some? If I call `Pickup().spawnShield()` then it shows my `var game: GameScene!` is nil. And I know thats the problem. What I'm asking is how do I make it reference my GameScene?

I tried something like this is my GameScene in my `didMove`:
`Pickup().game = self` but this still shows `var game` in my PickUp class as being nil.

Comment: If you do not create your own initializer, Swift creates automated, if default values for properties are set. If you call *Pickup().spawnShield()* and your game property is nil, have you set this *game* property in your *init()* initializer? Do you have such an initializer? What value do you put into *game* property? I none, then it is nil by default (default value for optionals is nil)